# Nice problem: Prove that: $ab+bc+ca \ge \sum{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+3}}$

Tags: inequality, summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method

Problem: Let $a,b,c>0:a+b+c=abc.$ Prove that: $$ab+bc+ca\ge \sqrt{a^2+b^2+3}+\sqrt{b^2+c^2+3}+\sqrt{c^2+a^2+3}$$
Please help me give a hint to get a nice proof!

My attempts after squaring both side, it is desired to show: $a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2+4(ab+bc+ca)\ge9+2\sum{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+3)(b^2+c^2+3)}}$

It seems I am lost!

Comment: Can you tell more help me dear sir?

Comment: Do you need to solve it algebraically? You can define $f(a,b,c) := ab + bc + ca - \sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+3} + \sqrt{a^{2}+c^{2}+3} + \sqrt{b^{2}+c^{2}+3}$ with a constraint function $g(a,b,c) := a+b+c-abc =0$. Then, find the minimum value of $f$ w.r.t. constraint function $g$ by using Lagrange Multiplier Method.

Comment: @Calvin Lin I checked. It's right.

Comment: @Evan William Chandra. Can you tell me more?

Comment: Essentially, the idea is to show that the aforementioned function $f$ with constraint $g=0$ has a nonnegative minimum value. Therefore, $f\geq0$ which is equivalent to your claim.

Again, this is probably not a "good" way to solve your problem but you might consider using this method if you are stuck somewhere along the way.

Ah also my bad, the function before "lacks brackets". It should be as follows
$f(a,b,c) := ab + bc + ca - (\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+3} + \sqrt{a^{2}+c^{2}+3} + \sqrt{b^{2}+c^{2}+3})$

Comment: @Evan William Chandra. I got it, thanks! The problem is also proven by just AM-GM.

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that:
$$ab+ac+bc\geq\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{abc}{a+b+c}\cdot\left(a^2+b^2+\frac{3abc}{a+b+c}\right)}$$ or
$$(ab+ac+bc)(a+b+c)\geq\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{abc((a^2+b^2)(a+b+c)+3abc)}.$$
Now, by AM-GM and C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(a+b+c)+3abc}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(a+b)+(a^2+b^2+3ab)c}\leq$$
$$\leq\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(a+b)+\frac{5(a+b)^2c}{4}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(a+b)(4a^2+4b^2+5(a+b)c)}\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(a+b)\sum_{cyc}(4a^2+4b^2+5(a+b)c)}=\sqrt{(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(4a^2+5ab)}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)^2\geq abc\sum_{cyc}(4a^2+5ab)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}c^3(a-b)^2\geq0.$$

Comment: Very nice proof, thanks. Any way, i think we also can use uwv to prove

Comment: @Phan Ngọc Châu Do you say about last inequality? If so, I think, it's unnecessary here. Indeed, this inequality is fifth degree and $uvw$ works, but SOS much more easier, I think.